# Class variables behave differently for list and int?

Tags: python, python-2.7

The class shared variables are shared with all the instances of the classes as far as I know. But I am having trouble getting my head around this.

```
class c():
    a=[1]
    b=1
    def __init__(self):
        pass

x=c()
x.a.append(1)
x.b+=1 #or x.b=2

print x.a #[1,1]
print x.b #2

y=c()
print y.a #[1,1] :As Expected
print y.b #1 :why not 2?
```

**y.a** resonates with the **x.a** but
**y.b** doesn't.

hope someone can clarify.

EDIT: And how can the same functionality be created for ints.

Comment: The lists are the same because they point to the same object, not necessarily because they are in a class.  The class is a red herring.  You can get the same behavior out of lists not in a class.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
x.a.append(1)
```

changes the class attribute `c.a`, a `list`, by calling its `append` method, which modifies the list in-place.

```
x.b += 1
```

is actually a shorthand for

```
x.b = x.b + 1
```

because integers in Python are immutable, so they don't have an `__iadd__` (in-place add) method. The result of this assignment is to set an attribute `b` on the instance `x`, with value `2` (the result of evaluating the right-hand side of the assignment). This new instance attribute shadows the class attribute.

To see the difference between an in-place operation and an assignment, try

```
x.a += [1]
```

and

```
x.a = x.a + [1]
```

These will have different behavior.

**EDIT** The same functionality can be obtained for integers by boxing them:

```
class HasABoxedInt(object):
    boxed_int = [0]    # int boxed in a singleton list

a = HasABoxedInt()
a.boxed_int[0] += 1
b = HasABoxedInt()
print(b.boxed_int[0])  # prints 1, not zero
```

or

```
class BoxedInt(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def __iadd__(self, i):
        self.value += i
```

Comment: So, you are suggesting that again the list be used for maintaining the staticness of the variable, and there is no way for ints be shared solely? 

And thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @TheAvs: it may be possible to subclass `int`, or otherwise implement a type with similar operations (like `BoxedInt`), and add an `__iadd__` to it. That would get hairy, though, so I'd use a `list` for this purpose.

Comment: @larsmans What purpose would an `__iadd__` have on an immutable object?

Comment: @glglgl: make it mutable. But you're right, subclassing `int` isn't the way to go. Emulating it via duck-typing is a better idea.

Answer (score 2):

larsmans' answer is excellent, but it might provide additional insight if we look at `id` of `x.b` before and after the assignment.

```
class c():
    a=[1]
    b=1
    def __init__(self):
        pass

x=c()

print "initial a : {} at {}".format(x.a, id(x.a))
print "initial b : {} at {}".format(x.b, id(x.b))

x.a.append(1)
x.b+=1 # x.b = x.b + 1, created a new object
       # we created an instance variable x.b and it
       # is shadowing the class variable b.  

print "after change a : {} at {}".format(x.a, id(x.a))
print "after change b : {} at {}".format(x.b, id(x.b))

y=c()

# We can already see from the class object that 
# b has not changed value
print "in class c b : {} at {}".format(c.b, id(c.b))

print "in instance y a : {} at {}".format(y.a, id(y.a))
print "in instance y b : {} at {}".format(y.b, id(y.b))
```

Result:

```
initial a : [1] at 50359040
initial b : 1 at 40974280
after change a : [1, 1] at 50359040
after change b : 2 at 40974256 # Shows id of instance variable x.b; hence it is
                               # different 
in class c b : 1 at 40974280
in instance y a : [1, 1] at 50359040
in instance y b : 1 at 40974280
```

If you want to use an `int` as a class variable, this should work:

```
class MyClass(object):
    b=1
    def increase_b(self, n):
        MyClass.b += n
```

Result:

```
>>> mc_1 = MyClass()
>>> mc_1.b
1
>>> mc_1.increase_b(5)
>>> mc_1.b
6
>>> mc_2 = MyClass()
>>> mc_2.b
6
>>> mc_2.increase_b(10)
>>> MyClass.b
16
>>> mc_2.b
16
>>> mc_1.b
16
```