Objects in class aren't working as intended
So a week ago, I learned about how classes work in python. I coded an experiment code as shown below:
class food:
    bowls = 0
    flavor = []

ramen = food()

ramen.flavor.append(["rameny","salty"])
ramen.bowls = 5
print(ramen.flavor)
print(ramen.bowls)

sushi = food()
print(sushi.flavor)
print(sushi.bowls)

If you run the code, you will notice that sushi and ramen flavors are the same even though I didn't do anything to the flavors of sushi. You can also notice that bowls prints correctly, with 5 being printed for ramen and 0 being printed for sushi as it should. So my question is, since all objects are unique and independent from each other, why is the flavors of ramen carrying over to sushi?
I asked my coding friend who introduced me to coding what went wrong and he wasn't able to find it out by the way.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18420078/class-variables-behave-differently-for-list-and-int
