# Instantiate object after a string python?

Tags: python

I have read many questions about this problem (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553784/can-you-use-a-string-to-instantiate-a-class-in-python)), suppose I have a string 'foo' and i want to instantiate an object named foo of a particular type.
What I would like to do is to be able to dynamically build an object adding properties extracted from an XML file (using the [Bunch](http://books.google.fr/books?id=9_AXCmGDiz8C&lpg=PA9&pg=PA34&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) pattern).

The problem I have is to name the "root" object(the bunch or the container) according to a particular string.

**EDIT**
I've realized that I could do something like

```
exec('%s = Bunch' % 'foo')
```

My bad

Comment: What do you mean by "an object named foo of a particular type"? Do you mean, "create an object and bind it to a variable named foo"? That's not going to be very useful, since your other code won't know to access the variable named `foo` to get at the object. Objects don't inherently have names in Python. That is, some objects may have multiple names while others have none.

Comment: I know it's a bit weird but I just have to provide objects to be used by other components built around the same xml files.

Comment: @LB. therefore the `object name` and `particular type` part of the question are irrelevant

Comment: the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18630827/2) should actually be put in the answers section.

Comment: There is absolutely *no* advantage in doing: `exec('%s = Bunch' % 'foo')` versus `foo = Bunch`. The only thing you do is to slow down the execution of the code. There *could* be an advantage if `foo` was an identifier containing a string created dynamically, but in this case this is a code smell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need something like this:

```
def parseXML(path):
    '''
    @return: {property: value}
    '''
    # ...


def Bunch():
    return type("XML", tuple(), parseXML(PATH))

foo = Bunch()
```

XML property value extractor should be implemented as suited.

You might want to have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18420423/1309352) while we are at *names* in Python.

Comment: not sure to understand but type() returns a type, right ? and what i'd like to do is to define a variable named 'foo'. I'd like to do :
foo = Bunch() and foo stems from an XML ....

Comment: @LB. You do *not* really want to do that. That's part of your solution, which is almost certainly *wrong*. *Having* to use `exec` is a **huge** code smell. I believe you fell victim of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and should really ask a question about how to design your code in order to *avoid* using `exec`, but this requires much more context.

Comment: @Bakuriu I know it really really smells...the thing is sometimes your client tells you what he wants. The thing is that I have to create a bunch and identify this bunch according to a string.